# Проверка пересечения вне объекта

Tags: unity3d

Если к объекту прикреплен скрипт, то в скрипте мы может определить момент пересечения коллайдера этого объекта через функцию например OnTriggerEnter2D.
А как можно не прикрепляя скрипт к объекту определить что один объект пересекается с другим? Например в скрипте нулл-объекта.

Answer (score 0):

создай запрос на проверку пересечения сферы с коллайдерами с центра даного пустого обьекта

```
void ExplosionDamage(Vector3 center, float radius)
{
    Collider[] hitColliders = Physics.OverlapSphere(center, radius);
    int i = 0;
    while (i < hitColliders.Length)
    {
        hitColliders[i].SendMessage("AddDamage");
        i++;
    }
}
```

детали

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.OverlapSphere.html

Comment: Привет, Andrew. Нам всем очень интересна ваша ситуация на SO. Не хотели бы ее обсудить с нами? Мнения про нее очень разные. Ссылка есть у VladD в [профиле](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd).